# EXTJS TextField Help in the side

Tags: extjs

I want to add like a ? beside of a TextField so as if the mouse pases over, it shows some help
How can I do it please.
Thnx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many ways to do this, and many different levels of complexity, but at it's simplest I might do something like this...

Add an interceptor function to the *Fields* init method that adds the question mark and uses qtip's to display a message - this allows all types of fields that inherit from the *Field* class to have this functionality.

For example:

```
Ext.intercept(Ext.form.Field.prototype, 'initComponent', function() {
  var fl = this.fieldLabel, h = this.helpText;
  if (h && h !== '' && fl) {
    this.fieldLabel = fl+'<span style="color:green;" ext:qtip="'+h+'">?</span> ';
  }
});
```

Then in each field definition you would have a *helpText* property:

```
{
   fieldLabel: 'First Name',
   helpText: 'This is your first name dummy!',
   name: 'first',
   allowBlank:false
}
```

This produces:

[image]

Im sure you can expand on it from what I have provided, and if you need more info on interceptors, check out my [blog post](http://www.vinylfox.com/patterns-using-ext-js-sequence-and-intercept/) on them.

Enjoy!